# How to create a Ubuntu server application with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I don't have any experience with Elastic Beanstalk and I need to create an application that runs t3 instances with Ubuntu installed as the OS.

However, When I create a new application (Web server or Worker), I don't see any Ubuntu pre-configuration. All I see is programming languages like `PHP` `Java` etc.

How can I create an Elastic Beanstalk application with Ubuntu-based instances?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Elastic Beanstalk Supported Platforms - AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html):

> All current Linux-based platform versions run on Amazon Linux 2018.03 (64-bit)

However, you can configure a **customer platform** to use Ubuntu.

See: [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Supports Custom Platforms](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-custom-platforms/)